# Is it possible to write multiple lines of comment for one #region scope?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Seems this question hasn't been asked. If it duplicates, please give a comment.

That's said I have the `#region` comment in C# code.

```
#region if this comment is very long, can I divide the comment into multi-lines?

   // my code is here

#endregion
```

Is it possible to divide the `#region` comment into multi-lines like the bottom code ?

```
#region the comment is separated into
#region-2 two lines.

   // my code is here

#endregion
```

Comment: Not as you would like to do it, but you can arbitrarily nest regions so you could make a facsimile but you may just want to consider better region names.

Comment: I'd like to see Studio support this someday.  Very often I have blocks of code that can be described with a comment, and I like to collapse those blocks of code.  I think "Private Members" is a horrible way to use regions, as it stretches apart the relationship of interdependent pieces (e.g. the public property that uses the private member).  But regions are useful around blocks of related code.  When used this way their titles are not standardized, they need to be descriptive.  The one-line limitation of the region text is slightly annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think long comments were the intended usage for the `#region` directive. When I think "region" I think things like "Private Members" or "Service Declarations" or "Overloaded Constructors" or a simple label of that nature.

If you have a long comment, I would instead include it at the top of the region, like this:

```
#region Some Region Name

    /**
     * Here is a decently lengthy comment which describes the
     * group of class members within the region.
     */

    /// <summary>
    /// A regular member's comment documentation.
    /// </summary>
    public int MyRegionProperty { get; set; }

    // etc...

#endregion
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes the part that comes after `#region` as a "name", not a comment. Names should be descriptive enough to identify what's in the region, nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

Definition of `#Region` from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> `#region lets you specify a block of code that you can expand or collapse when using the outlining feature of the Visual Studio Code Editor. In longer code files, it is convenient to be able to collapse or hide one or more regions so that you can focus on the part of the file that you are currently working on.'

Its Primary purpose is to allow for outlining your code and being able to collapse areas(regions) for readability. If you want extended comments you will have to use Standard C# commenting

Answer (score 1):

Region is used to Group up code chunks which can be expanded and collapsed,not for commenting :

[image]

browse this http://www.dotnetperls.com/region